# Don't want to receive emails I sent to groups which I'm included in them

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

When I send emails to groups which my email address is also in there I prefer not to get the email. I think Outlook (2010) should automatically figure that I sent the email and I'm part of the group so there is no reason for me (the sender) to receive the email which I sent! :-)

I hope I was clear.

Any suggestions will be great!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are part of the group, so, you will get group emails.

The only way I know of is to create a new rule that automatically deletes messages that come to the group which are from you.

For example, my name is `William Hilsum` and my company has a group called "London Office".

If I create the following rule, this will work perfectly:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was going to do this for a user, but I recently upgraded to Office 2013 and couldn't help but notice that I no longer receive emails that I send to groups that I am also a member of. It appears that Outlook 2013 is smart enough to filter this out for you.

Comment: This would be better as a comment